# How to use C++ template to have function code based on it

Tags: c++

I want to have a class in which one function will depend on the a template that is defined in the instantiation... Like

```
MyClass<Client1> instance;
instance1.function1();

MyClass<Client2> instance2;
instance2.function1();
```

then it will use function1 based on that, but I don't want to have to redeclare the whole class for each template, just function1.

How do I declare the class and function?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, a normal template class will do.

Comment: Are you looking for member function templates? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to provide an implementation for a single method of a class template. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct MyClass {
    void function1();
    void common() { std::cout << "common stuff\n"; }
};

class Client1;
class Client2;

template<>
void MyClass<Client1>::function1()
{
    std::cout << "stuff 1\n";
}

template<>
void MyClass<Client2>::function1()
{
    std::cout << "stuff 2\n";
}

int main()
{
    MyClass<Client1> instance1;
    instance1.function1();
    instance1.common();

    MyClass<Client2> instance2;
    instance2.function1();
    instance2.common();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem you wouldn't exactly *need* templates for, you just want a function to act based of a condition passed into the class?

```
private:
    bool IsStateActive;

//MyClass.cpp

MyClass::MyClass(bool state)
{
    IsStateActive=state;
}

MyClass::function1()
{
    if(state)
        //....
    else
        //.....
}
```

of course state could also an enum if you would like multiple states as well..

```
enum { CLIENT1=0, CLIENT2, CLIENT3}
MyClass newObj(CLIENT1); //sets an int to CLIENT0 to be used during function1
```

why exactly would you like to use templates for this?

Answer (score -1):

you can specialize the function for each instance of the template

Comment: Could explain how to do it?

Comment: sorry for late reply. you can refer to the solution of jork